# Android Firebase authentication: federated Google login not working in Oreo

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

This piece of codes:

```
private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
    .addOnCompleteListener(this, task -> {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
            FirebaseUser user = task.getResult().getUser();
            mMainViewModel.setGoogleLoginResult(user);
        } else {
            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
            mMainViewModel.setGoogleLoginResult(null);
        }
    });
}
```

That I got from here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin

Working just fine on Nougat devices, but its not working on Oreo devices.

These are my build.gradle:

```
compileSdkVersion 28
buildToolsVersion '28.0.0'

// Firebase
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1"
```

I've already debug both on each device; working (Nougat) and not-working one (Oreo) but found no differences.

Any clues?

Comment: what do you mean by "not working"? Do you get any error messages?

Comment: Its not calling .addOnCompleteListener. Neither success or failed. No error messages in logcat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got some assistance from Firebase team in the past few days, and some how this morning the codes just works (on Oreo devices). There is nothing I've been done on my side, don't know what they've been done.